# Telegram bot api and Webhook with SSL

Tags: python, ssl, tornado, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I create simple tornado http server with ssl_options and set web hook for Telegram bot, but server didn't get "post" request. What problem can be?

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        print('Post request')

    def get(self):
        print('Get request')
        self.write('<h1>Hello, World</h1>')

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', MainHandler)
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application, ssl_options={
        'certfile': 'server.crt',
        'keyfile': 'server.key'
    })
    http_server.listen(443)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Answer (score 2):

When issuing a self-signed SSL certificate, make sure 'Common Name' matches your FQDN (`hostname -f`).

Example:

`$ openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout server.key -out server.crt -days 3650`

If you are using `python-telegram-bt` you can test SSL handshake running [this](https://gist.github.com/leandrotoledo/4e9362acdc5db33ae16c) script and trying to connect using wget:

`$ wget -O /dev/null https://$HOST:$PORT/`